# optaplanner with constraintprovider sometimes throws nulpointer exception

Tags: optaplanner

I made a constraint solver using vrp examples.
it works well with easyscorecalculator.

I changed scorecalculator from easyscorecalculator to constraintprovider.
But, Sometimes constraint provider throws nullpointer exception while constructing heuristics.
this error is not reproducible, sometimes it occurred error, but most time it works well.

### constraints defined

```java
    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return new Constraint[]{

                // Hard Constraints
                arrivalAfterDueTime(factory),
                vehicleCapacity(factory),
                lowCarOnlyLoadJumboItems(factory),
                topCarOnlyLoadSmallItems(factory),
                maxDistanceConstraints(factory),
                vehicleLengthPenalty(factory),

                // Soft Constraints
                shortPenalty(factory),
                dummyPenalty(factory),
                consolidationPenalty1(factory),
                consolidationPenalty2(factory),
                consolidationPenalty3(factory),
                distanceToPreviousStandstill(factory),
                distanceFromLastCustomerToDepot(factory),


        };
    }
```

### error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (7) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:187)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:158)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:175)
    at com.cello.rapid.edo.engine.controller.EngineController.runEngine(EngineController.java:54)
    at com.cello.rapid.edo.engine.RollingTest.testOrderEventLinkServiceController(RollingTest.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

> ***Caused by: Exception executing consequence for rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill" in com.cello.rapid.edo.engine.domain:
> java.lang.NullPointerException***
    at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:1056)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:462)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:102)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:869)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:816)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:808)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1343)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1334)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:90)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:147)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.AbstractRuleContext.runConsequence(AbstractRuleContext.java:58)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.UniRuleContext.lambda$newRuleBuilder$9ef14e2e$1(UniRuleContext.java:52)
    at org.drools.model.functions.Block3$Impl.execute(Block3.java:40)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.consequence.LambdaConsequence.evaluate(LambdaConsequence.java:75)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:455)
    ... 18 more
```

### code (this is the same with vrp example)

```java
protected Constraint distanceToPreviousStandstill(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Customer.class)
            .penalizeLong("distanceToPreviousStandstill",
                    BendableLongScore.ofSoft(BENDABLE_SCORE_HARD_LEVELS_SIZE,
    BENDABLE_SCORE_SOFT_LEVELS_SIZE, 3, 1),
                    Customer::getDistanceFromPreviousStandstill);
}
```

I am seeking to find the reason, but i could not. TT
your cooperation would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the actual exception being thrown. See that the cause is speaking of an NPE, but never actually does give us the NPE - so we can not see from its stack trace which code it was that caused the issue. As a side note, I see moveThreadIndex (7) - we recommend never going over 4 move threads, as our multithreaded solver doesn't scale well past 4. 7 is just wasting resources.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you have provided the full stack trace? When I make my consequence throw an NPE, the message does include the NPE's stack trace.

Comment: 1) What happens if you run with `environmentMode=FULL_ASSERT` and also with `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`? The input data might be corrupted. 2) Really weird that it doesn't reproduce every time, I don't see how the move thread arbitrary scheduling could cause this race condition. Try using moveThreadCount=NONE and play with the randomSeed until you reproduce on every single run. And don't use simulated annealing if you're using that.